# PHP: $_REQUEST is not showing value of get parameter

Tags: php, http, get, request, backend

I'm running into a strange problem where `$_REQUEST` is not showing the value of a parameter I am explicitly passing e.g.

http://example.com/strange.php?parName=1234

`strange.php`:

```
<?php 
$foo = $_REQUEST['parName'] ;
echo $foo ;
?>
```

I have looked in the Inspector and the Network tab actually shows the correct query string parameter.

Comment: That has the same outcome :( Tried that first

Comment: and use `isset()` and/or `!empty()` with a conditional statement. `if(condition) {...} else {...}` probably getting an undefined notice since you're probably running this from the same file.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_REQUEST['parName'])` say ?

Comment: any rewrite rule in your .htaccess file?

Comment: How do you pass the parameter? [REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) contains only `POST`, `GET` & `COOKIE`. So, if you for some reason use `PUT`, this won't work.

Comment: question's gone stale.

Comment: Sorry, I just ended up working around it :(

Answer (score 0):

I have carried out some tests.

in **test.html:**

```
<a href="request.php?parName=1234">link</a>
```

in **request.php:**

```
$foo = $_REQUEST['parName'];
echo $foo ;
```

I have also tried:

```
$foo = $_GET['parName'];
echo $foo ;
```

Both of which work.

Therefore thinking about the strange issue you are encountering, you will need carry out various checks:

1. Is the query string getting passed?  See $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
2. Check the request method $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]
3. Check to see if the parName variable isset

   ```
   if(isset($_GET['parName'] )) {
   $foo = $_GET['parName'];
   echo $foo ;
   }
    else { "echo query string not received";
   }
   ```
4. Check your error log to see what Apache is saying?
5. What data is actually contained in the parName variable?

   ```
   var_dump($_REQUEST['parName'])
   ```

Once you've run all these tests, and the issue is still not resolved, please post your results so we can consider other possible paths to solving this problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Have provided a more comprehensive answer.